# Do BIP199's HTLCs suffer from script malleability?

Tags: multi-signature, transaction-malleability, hash-time-locked-contract

Do [BIP199](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0199.mediawiki) HTLCs suffer from sigscript malleability like multisigs do due to OP_CHECKMULTISIG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Script define in [bip-0199](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0199.mediawiki) may suffer from [`OP_IF` malleability](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2016-August/013014.html) if not used in a witness Script (which enforces that the argument to `OP_IF` is minimal, that is either the empty vector or `0x01`).

There may be other malleability sources in this Script that i didn't spot, and more generally malleability being very difficult to reason about it's worth using tools such as [Miniscript](http://bitcoin.sipa.be/miniscript/) to prevent your Script's satisfaction(s) to be (too much) malleable.